# how to text align on top of each other in CSS and make image width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am having trouble figuring out how to make the text align on top of each other and aligned in one single line rather than breaking apart on a new line.

also, the width of the image doesn't fill all my browser but rather, cuts the image and uses the default theme background color.

solutions to those two problems would be fantastic.

here's what i have

```css
/* Header */

.large-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 514px;
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.demo-1 .large-header {
    background-image: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/P2IQDFK9VC.jpg');
}

.demo-3 .large-header {
    background: #7f8c8d;
}

.main-title {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #f9f1e9;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.main-title1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #f9f1e9;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.main-title2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #f9f1e9;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.main-title3 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #f9f1e9;
    text-align: center;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.demo-1 .main-title,
.demo-3 .main-title {
    font-size: 3.2em;
}

.demo-3 .main-title {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: 10px double #f9f1e9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-title .thin {}

@media only screen and (max-width: autopx) {
    .demo-1 .main-title,
}
```

```html
<div class="container demo-1">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="large-header" class="large-header">
            <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
            <h1 class="main-title" style="font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; text-align: justify ;">Sigma Phi Delta Fraternity</h1><br>
            <h2 class="main-title1" style="text-align: justify">The Premier International Fraternity of Engineers</h2><br>
            <h3 class="main-title2">San Diego State University - Beta Lambda</h3><br>
            <div class="btn btn-warning-outline hover main-title3">
                <a href="https://securelb.imodules.com/s/1247/aff_1_home.aspx?sid=1247" style="text-decoration: none; " class="btn-1 btn-1a ">
                    National Website
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers to your questions

*i am having trouble figuring out how to make the text align on top of each other and aligned in one single line rather than breaking apart on a new line.*

use `line-height: 10px;` for this, it will adjust the spacing of the letters for you

*also, the width of the image doesn't fill all my browser but rather, cuts the image and uses the default theme background color.*

you need to apply the background image to the body tag not just the large-header as you did in the example. the default css stylesheet of your browser will take preference if you and probably has padding in your case. This is why you have a border just outside of your image.

There is also a whole bunch of things you don't need in css that you have, unless this is just a snippet of a larger project that you pasted. I reformatted in the example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/aatjs2gu/

Comment: it is, it's part of a bigger project, thats why i didn't use background image, because the theme's background is already set to white, and excuting the code would make the image cover the whole website.

the following is a picture of the problem i'm still experiencing. 
http://i.imgur.com/Xpr8VLp.png

all the extra code is to display that dots being linked effect